# Module.create dosen't take data from input, req.body is empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, axios

I am currently working on a project and there was a problem entering the mongo db input data:

**app.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const getAdminPannel = require('./routes/pannelRoute');
const getView = require('./routes/viewRoutes');

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.use('/api/v1/services',getAdminPannel);

//Views routes
app.use('/',getView);


module.exports = app;
```

routes folder
**pannelRoute.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const pannelController = require('../controller/pannelController');
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/create-services')
      .post(pannelController.createPannelServices);

module.exports = router;
```

controller folder
**pannelController**

```
exports.createPannelServices = async(req,res) =>{
    try{
        const createService = Service.create(req.body);
        console.log(req.body)
        res.status(201).json({
           length:createService.lengnth,
           status:"Success",
           data:{
               services:createService
           }
        });
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json({
            status:'Fail',
            message:'Invalid data request'
        });
    }
}
```

**script.js** file where I take data from input sublit action:

```
import {createService} from './createService';

const createServices = document.querySelector('.createServiceForm');
if(createServices){
    createServices.addEventListener('submit',(el)=>{
          el.preventDefault();
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append('serviceName',document.getElementById('servicename_create').value);
        form.append('serviceDescription',document.getElementById('serviceDescription').value);
      
        
          createService(form)
    })
}
```

**createService.js** script file where I use axios to inser data using api link.

```
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
import axios from 'axios';
import { showAlert } from './alert';

export const createService = async(data)=>{
    try{
        const create = await axios({
            method:'POST',
            url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/services/create-services',
            service:data
        });
        if(create.data.status === 'success'){
             showAlert('success','Servicul a fost creeat!!!');
             window.setTimeout(()=>{
                 location.assign('/');
             }, 1500);
         }
         console.log(data);
    }catch(err){
        showAlert('error','A aparut o problema in procesul de creeare a servicului!!!');
    }
    
}
```

the problem is that req.body does not return any value is empty and that error also appears

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `createService.js` you aren't passing the data correctly to axios.

You'll want to change it to this:

```
const create = await axios({
  method:'POST',
  url:'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/services/create-services',
  data:data
});
```

`req.body` on the backend corresponds to the `data` field, which you weren't populating before.

Answer (score 0):

Try `axios.post` in the `createService.js`

```js
const create = await axios.post(
   'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/services/create-services',
   data,
   { headers: data.getHeaders() }
);

//print body response
console.log(create.data);
```